# Matlab: replace one plot maintaining others

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a figure in which I plot some disperse points and then a trajectory. I want to switch between different trajectories by plotting them in the same figure as the points, but without creating new figures, i.e., "erasing" the first trajectory and then plotting the new one.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you at least provided a small example of how you are plotting now without erasing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this little demo will be helpful:

```
xy = rand(20,2);
figure
% Plot first iteration and output handles to each
h = plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'b.',xy(1:2,1),xy(1:2,2),'r-');
axis([0 1 0 1])

% Update second plot by setting the XData and YData properties of the handle
for i = 2:size(xy,1)-1
    set(h(2),{'XData','YData'},{xy(i:i+1,1),xy(i:i+1,2)})
    drawnow
    pause(0.1);
end
```

You should read up on [handle graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) in Matlab and the [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) functions.