# MATLAB's drawnow doesn't flush

Tags: matlab

Is there any reason that MATLAB's drawnow wouldn't flush?

This is my code:

```
j=1;
for k = 1:length(P)
    for i = 1:n
        plot(P(k,j),P(k,j+1),'.');
        j = j+2;
    end
    axis equal
    axis([-L L -L L]);
    j=1;
    drawnow
end
```

(`rungekutta4` is my own function I wrote, and it works OK, so the problem isn't there.)

The particles just stay drawn on the plot and don't get overwritten every time the loop executes.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: You may what to flush before drawing. Try `clf`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it animates only one particle :/

Comment: It animates the amount of particles you draw! Depends where you have put it, of course. You need to put it before the `for i=1:n` line. After, write a `hold on`.

Answer (score 2):

The proper and efficient way to do this is with [handle graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html). You should also vectorize your `plot` commands.

```
% Example data to make runnable
L = 1;
n = 10; % Number of points
P = 2*rand(1e2,n+1)-1;

% Initialize plot, first iteration
h = plot(P(1,1:n),P(1,2:n+1),'.'); % Plot first set of points and return handle
axis equal;
axis([-L L -L L]);
hold on; % Ensure axis properties are fixed
drawnow;

% Animate
for k = 2:size(P,1) % size is safer in this case
    % Use handle to update the positions of the previously plotted points
    set(h,{'XData','YData'},{P(k,1:n),P(k,2:n+1)});
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1); % Slow down animation a bit to make visible
end
```

Calling `clf` and/or `plot` on each iteration of an animation causes many things already in memory to be unnecessarily deleted and reallocated, resulting much slower code. It may also result in flickering in some cases.

See also [this very similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501586/matlab-replace-one-plot-maintaining-others).

Comment: yep, this question seems to come back regularly. Do you really need the `hold on` statement ? when I answered the same question before (a few times already) in the same way you did, I was also explaining that `plot` will recreate a plot and recalculate/readjust all the axis limits and other properties, while using `set` on the `X/YData` only update that and nothing else, so the axis limits and other properties would not change.

Comment: @Hoki: You're right, in this simple example you probably don't need it, but I've not tested in old versions of Matlab. However, I often put it there anyways because I may end up inserting other commands before or within the animation loop that could result in changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to animate something, you want to, of course, force draw. Thats what the command `drawnow` is there for. But there are other things to consider!

One of them is that you need to make sure that everything is drawn in each frame. For that, use the `hold on` function just before you start drawing (plot).

However, you also need to make sure that you clear the image before drawing, else the plots will stack forever. Use the `clf` "clear figure`command before the previously mentioned`hold on` and that will do the job.

remember that if the animation is too fast you can always add a `pause(0.2)` line after `drawnow` to slow it.